# Expected value for random k-element subset

Tags: expected-value

Let $m\ge1$, $n\ge1$, and $k\ge1$ be integers with $k\le m + n$. Consider a set $P$ consisting of $m$ men and $n$ women. We choose a uniformly random $k$-element subset $Q$ of $P$. Consider the random variables

- $X$ = the number of men in the chosen subset $Q$,
- $Y$ = the number of women in the chosen subset $Q$,
- $Z = X − Y$.

Determine the expected value ${\rm E}(X)$.

Prove that ${\rm E}(Z) = k\dfrac{m - n}{m + n}$.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck? What kind of things have you learned recently that might be useful tools in tackling this problem?

Comment: As a small hint - note that Y = k - X and hence Z = 2X - k, so once you figure out one expectation you can use linearity of expectations for the other two.

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE. Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) when writing equations to make them easier to read.